# SSL handshake failure in android

Tags: android, ssl, xmpp

i'm trying to implement xmpp client in android it works finr in desktop systems means where the openfire kept....but when i'm trying to connect remote systems it showa sslhandshake failure  failure ssl library protocol error

please help me to resolve this issue

thanks regards renuka

Comment: Some code and an error message will help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Handshake errors are often caused by a mismatch in the available ciphersuites on the client and server side.  If you're using GnuTLS client-side, it might also be the same [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls26/+bug/418935) that Empathy has.